# Search for file that contains specific content

Tags: windows, windows-10

Trying to figure out how to create complicated search in Windows 10. I need to search in particular folder and its subfolders for *.cpp file that contains line "#include <libxml/parser.h>". How to achieve that by using Windows. I put `*.cpp` ini search box, but how to define containing line?

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell to the Rescue

1. Open a PowerShell terminal window.
2. Enter the following command, changing the path as necessary.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folderToSearch\*.cpp -Recurse | Select-String "#include <libxml/parser.h>"
```

### How it Works

`Get-ChildItem` searches the specified folder for all *.cpp files recursively. All file objects found are then piped to `Select-String` which searches each file for the string you're interested in.

### Example

[image: Sample use case showing command results]

Answer (score 0):

You may search in Explorer text using the `content:` pragma.For example:

```
content:"#include <libxml/parser.h>" *.cpp
```

(Note: I'm not too sure about how do work special characters like `<`, `>` and `/`.
You may need to omit them in case of a problem.)

The file-type `.cpp` must be defined as indexable:

- Run Indexing Options from the Start menu
- Click the "Advanced" button
- Switch to the “File Types” tab
- Ensure that "cpp" is checked (this is the default unless changed).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether if you mean a file on the Internet or what?
But if you're asking about files on the Internet i.e:You can just instead go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and search for that webpage.